# centering a sprite in the middle of the screen convertToWorldSpace / NodeSpace

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

i have passed many many days on this problem, i've not very clear in mind what convertToWorldSpace, convertToNodeSpace does...

i have 2 layer (CCNode) one that i can scale, one for panning the screen, so i scale always what is displayed makeing the center of scaling the middle of the screen:

```
scaleLayer=[CCNode node];
scaleLayer.position= ccp( size.width /2 , size.height/2 );
[self addChild:scaleLayer z:-2000];

panLayer=[CCNode node];
panLayer.position= ccp( -size.width /2 , -size.height/2 );
[scaleLayer addChild:panLayer z:-2000];
```

now i add sprites to panlayer:
[panLayer addChild:mysprite z:2];

i'd like to have a button that, when pressed, moves panlayer to make the sprite in the middle of the screen.
i have wrote this but works only if scaleLayer.scale=1

```
CGPoint p;
p=[panLayer convertToWorldSpace:mysprite.position];
p.x=(panLayer.position.x+(240-p.x));
p.y=(panLayer.position.y+(160-p.y));
[panLayer runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.5 position:p]];
```

how can i make the sprite to be at center of the screen with different scales?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your existing code does but you might find the property `mysprite.boundingBox` useful.  It will give you a `CGRect` with the sprite's width and height and the position of its bottom left corner, and it will reflect whatever scale you have applied to the sprite.

Comment: in this code i find the position in pixel of the sprite, i have a translation of the panlayer suppose x=+100, so i have to tranlsate the sprite (suppose in position x=+20), so the sprite is in pos: x=+120, then i translate back -120 pixel+ the center of the screen, 240 pixel. if i scale i must find the position in pixel in scale layer,not world. hope this explanation is not too foggy